# How do I make this merge sort go in descending order rather than ascending?

Tags: java, mergesort

This is probably a fairly simple problem. I just can't figure out how to make this sort in descending order rather than ascending. Can anyone help me out?

```
public static void sortYear(Movie4[] movies, int low, int high)
{
    if ( low == high ) 
        return; 
    int mid = ( low + high ) / 2; 
    sortYear( movies, low, mid ); 
    sortYear( movies, mid + 1, high ); 

    mergeYears(movies, low, mid, high ); 
}

public static void mergeYears(Movie4[] movies, int low, int mid, int high)
{

    Movie4[] temp = new Movie4[ high - low + 1 ]; 
    int i = low, j = mid + 1, n = 0; 
    while ( i <= mid || j <= high ) 
    { 
        if ( i > mid ) 
        { 
            temp[ n ] = movies[ j ]; 
            j++; 
        } 
        else if ( j > high ) 
        { 
            temp[ n ] = movies[ i ]; 
            i++; 
        } 
        else if ( movies[ i ].getYear() < movies[ j ].getYear()) 
        {   
            temp[n] = movies[i];
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            temp[n] = movies[j];
            j++;
        }
        n++;
    }   
    for ( int k = low ; k <= high ; k++ ) 
    {
        movies[ k ] = temp[ k - low ]; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, he said so... Right at the end of the question...

Comment: It is homework, but it's not the entire problem. I have to write a program using a descending merge sort and I can't figure it out. There's nothing wrong with looking that up.

Comment: `"so I'm just going to keep typing for a little while"` - yeah, you're not supposed to do that.

Answer (score 5):

In an attempt to help you answer the question yourself, I'll add some comments to the code.

All of the real work is in mergeYears:

```
public static void mergeYears(Movie4[] movies, int low, int mid, int high)
{

    Movie4[] temp = new Movie4[ high - low + 1 ]; 

    // 'i' tracks the index for the head of low half of the range.
    // 'j' tracks the index for the head of upper half of the range.
    int i = low, j = mid + 1, n = 0; 

    // While we still have a entry in one of the halves.
    while ( i <= mid || j <= high ) 
    { 
        // Lower half is exhausted.  Just copy from the upper half.
        if ( i > mid ) 
        { 
            temp[ n ] = movies[ j ]; 
            j++; 
        } 
        // Upper half is exhausted. Just copy from the lower half.
        else if ( j > high ) 
        { 
            temp[ n ] = movies[ i ]; 
            i++; 
        } 
        // Compare the two Movie4 objects at the head of the lower and upper halves.
        // If lower is less than upper copy from lower.
        else if ( movies[ i ].getYear() < movies[ j ].getYear()) 
        {   
            temp[n] = movies[i];
            i++;
        }
        // Lower is is greater than upper.  Copy from upper.
        else
        {
            temp[n] = movies[j];
            j++;
        }
        n++;
    }

    // Copy from the temp buffer back into the 'movie' array.
    for ( int k = low ; k <= high ; k++ ) 
    {
        movies[ k ] = temp[ k - low ]; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To change the order of the sorting, you have to worry about the exact place where they compare the objects' values. In your case, that's in the line below.

Just change this:

```
else if ( movies[ i ].getYear() < movies[ j ].getYear())
```

To this:

```
else if ( movies[ i ].getYear() > movies[ j ].getYear())
```

Notice that the only thing that changed is the `>` operator.